Is this mathematically correct that gradient of deformation gradient is equal to deformation gradient?
The deformation matrix is defined as follows, where $x$ is the current location and $X$ is the reference location. It shows the relationship between current $x$s with regard to original $X$s,
$$F = \frac{\partial x}{\partial X}$$
Can I apply chain rule here
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x(X)}{\partial X}(x) =?\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}$$
Does that mean
$$\nabla F = F$$
This question might be related to What is the gradient of deformation gradient $F$? . I have seen that answer, but I still have a hard time grabbing this.
To further extend this question. What might be the meaning of operator
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{\partial }{\partial X}$$ on $f(x)$

Could you clarify what you did in the chain rule step?

@Amogh I am actually a bit confused there as well. I am treating right most x as a function X which is x(X). and dx/dX as a function of x which is dx/dX(x). But the chain rule indicates that dx on the denominator and nominator should cancel.
